# Error creating bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, javabeans

I'm getting the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'preTransactionHandlerPool' defined in class com.fg.transbridge.processor.spring.ContextConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I have the `preTransactionHandlerPool` bean alredy.

```
@Bean(name = "preTransactionHandlerPool")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor preTransactionHandlerPool() {

        LOGGER.info("Initializing preTransactionHandlerPool");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(preTransCorePoolSize);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(preTransMaxPoolSize);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(preWaitForCompleteShutDown);
        LOGGER.debug("Initiated preTransactionHandlerPool");
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
```

What could be the reason for that?
Highly appreciate your help.

**Thank You**

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException`, so likely you are feeding it the wrong data. Could you please post more of your code on the creation of the bean?

Comment: @bas edited it as u said

Comment: Are you certain that `"preTransactionHandlerPool"` is a correct value? It appears as though it is an Illegal Argument for this method.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace from spring? Spring does not only emit a single line but a whole bunch of information (including a stack trace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, found the correct answer. The method has some errors. The values pass should be `setMaxPoolSize > setCorePoolSize` in my case.